# How to create 2D arrays or collections of custom classes in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba, class

I have a custom class, and 700 instances of this class. Some of these instances share the same value for a specific property (TourID). I want to assemble these instances in a 2D array or a collection based on the value of their TourID.

Creating a 2D array gives me a Type Mismatch error, and creating a Collection doesn't allow me to assign a key with the value of the TourID to the items.

```
Dim list_of_stops() As New Stops
For i = 0 To UBound(list_tours)
LastValue = Ubound(list_of_stops(list_tours(i).TourID))
Redim Preserve list_of_stops(list_tours(i).TourID, LastValue + 1)
list_of_stops(list_tours(i).TourID, LastValue) = list_tours(i)
Next
```

I would like to have list_of_stops() structured in the following way:

```
list_of_stops(1,0) = first stop with tour ID = 1
list_of_stops(1,1) = second stop with tour ID = 1
...
list_of_stops(1,n) = n-th stop with tour ID = 1
...
list_of_stops(n,n) = n-th stop with tour ID = n
```

Comment: How does `LastValue = Ubound(list_of_stops(list_tours(i).TourID))` make sense when `list_of_stops()` has not yet been dimensioned? In any event, 1) a dictionary rather than a collection might be a good choice and 2) a [mcve] would help. We can't actually run your code without undue effort.

Comment: Also -- the `New` in your array declaration line doesn't really make sense

Comment: @JohnColeman it makes each array element be an auto-instanciated object... which is weird indeed (never seen that), but apparently legal. `Dim foo(1 To 10) As New Collection` and then `Debug.Print foo(2) Is Nothing` will output `False` even if you never set any subscript to any object reference.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Interesting. I'm surprised that it is legal.

Answer (score 2):

I can't explain why you would be getting a *type mismatch* error without seeing more of your code (declarations, mainly), but without a `Set` keyword the assignment is probably causing let-coercion, which fails (although, I'm missing something, because that would be error 91, or if the class has a *default property*, the closest I get to a type mismatch is a compile-time "invalid use of property").

Regardless, your life would be simplier with a `Dictionary` keyed with the unique `TourID` values, holding a `Collection` of all instances with that `TourID` value.

Reference the *Microsoft Scripting Runtime* library (`Scripting`):

```
Dim values As Dictionary
Set values = New Dictionary ' avoid "As New" unless you *NEED* an auto-instantiated object

Dim k As Variant
Dim currentGroup As Collection
For Each k In GetUniqueValuesForTourID 'TODO: a function that returns the unique IDs
    Set currentGroup = New Collection
    Dim v As Variant
    For Each v In GetAllValuesForTourID(k) 'TODO: a function that returns the records for given ID
        currentGroup.Add v, k 'note: Collection.Add value, key
    Next
    Set values(k) = currentGroup 'note the "Set" keyword; or: Dictionary.Add key, value
Next
```

Now if you iterate the dictionary entries, each item is a `Collection`, and in each collection each item is a `Stops` instance (why is it pluralized? is it a custom collection class?). This makes it very easy to instantly retrieve a collection of all `Stops`, given a `TourID`.